# NUnit copying ILogicalThreadAffinative items in CallContext to new threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, nunit

I've run into an issue with NUnit and CallContext (using C#) where NUnit is copying the anything in the existing call context that extends ILogicalThreadAffinative when a new thread is created. For example, in the following example an exception is always thrown in the newly-created thread:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestCopiedCallContext()
    {
        Foo f = new Foo();
        f.a = 1;
        CallContext.SetData("Test", f);
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
        {
            if (CallContext.GetData("Test") != null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Bad!");
            }
        })).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }

    class Foo : ILogicalThreadAffinative
    {
        public int a;
    }
```

If Foo doesn't extend ILogicalThreadAffinative then the test passes. I'm using .NET 2.0 (due to other restrictions we cannot use newer versions of .NET). I've also tried using the Requires* attributes available in the latest version of NUnit but with no success. Does anyone know how to turn this behavior off?

Answer (score 0):

I dont beleive that you can do what you are attempting to do.  One person has suggested putting the code into an assembly where the test runner has access to it.

There is a [blog post](http://averyblog.com/net/callcontext-and-nunit-woes/) that you probably know about, that describes what the issue is.

Unit testing code that does multithreading can be challenging and I tend to isolate threads and wrap static objects.

If it were me, I think that I would try to isolate CallContext.SetData and CallContext.GetData by wrapping call context in a class CallContextWrapper : ICallContextWrapper.

The I would test that my code uses contextWrapper.SetData("Test", f) and be done with it;

I would trust that whoever wrote CallContext tested it's ability to take in some data and transfer it to a new thread.  IMO CallContext is framework code that should have already been tested so you just need to isolate your code's dependency on CallContext.